# Vertical UIScrollView with maximum y position on subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a vertical UIScrollView with 2 buttons. I need to make it so when you scroll, the buttons hit the top of the iPhone screen and then no longer scroll with the UIScrollView until the scroll view has come back down.

Here is what the page looks like:

[image: Example Image]

The My Polls and Following buttons, when scrolled up, need to stay below the blue bar that says "Me" on it. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks! (I am using Objective-C)

Comment: Why not to pin this buttons in Interface Builder above your ScrollView to the top?

Comment: @schmidt9 because I need it to move with the scroll view when scrolling. It's hard to explain why in this case that is essential. Also, I am doing most of this programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out finally. Here is my code:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint menuBarPointRelevantToScreen = [self.view convertPoint:self.menuBarView.frame.origin fromView:self.menuBarView];
    int yOfMenuBarWhenScrolling = menuBarPointRelevantToScreen.y-scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    int bottomOfTopBarView = self.topBarView.frame.origin.y+self.topBarView.frame.size.height;
    if(yOfMenuBarWhenScrolling < bottomOfTopBarView && self.menuBarView.superview == self.parentScrollView){
        [self.menuBarView removeFromSuperview];
        [POUIConstraintManager spaceTopOf:self.menuBarView fromBottomOf:self.topBarView space:0];
        [self.view addSubview:self.menuBarView];
    }
    else if(scrollView.contentOffset.y<=constantMenuBarY && self.menuBarView.superview == self.view){
        [self.menuBarView removeFromSuperview];
        [self setupMenuBarPosition];
        [self.parentScrollView addSubview:self.menuBarView];
    }
}
```

It's hard to explain but hopefully the code above helps someone. Basically I am doing as follows:
First I need to figure out how far away the menu items ("My Polls, Following") are from the top bar ("Me"). In order to accomplish this I take the y coordinate of the menu items in relevance to the view that contains everything (same view the top bar ("Me") is on). Then I just subtract the y offset of the scroll view from that and that gives me the distance between the two.
From there I just use an if statement to figure out if the menu bar has touched the top bar so I can take it off the scroll view and add it to the same view the top bar is on keeping it directly under the top bar until the scroll view has come back down.

(Note: constantMenuBarY is just a constant integer that the menu bar is suppose to be at when on the scroll view and POUIConstraintManager is just a class I made to more easily position views)

I hope that at least makes some sense. Anyone trying to figure this out will probably best off just taking a look at the code.

**UPDATE:**
I've had to improve this with some essential changes to make it work in various cases. If anyone needs help with this leave a comment I can work on explaining it better.